# Why is my Spring application working with @RestController but not with @Controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

I am following a tutorial on Spring applications in which the instructor is building a basic Spring MVC application.  The instructor is using Eclipse without a build manager, but I am using IntelliJ Ultimate with Gradle.  I'm not sure if that is important, but I'm including to be transparent.

In the very first project, the instructor created an app that looks like this.

```
package com.example.springdemo.mvc;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.Controller;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showPage(){
        return "main-menu";
    }
}
```

When I run the project, I get a whitelabel error page.
[image: WhiteLabel Error Page]

However, when I run the program with @RestController instead of @Controller, it works fine.  The instructor doesn't go over the @RestController, and I'd prefer to follow the project the same as the instructor is doing it, but nothing I do seems to work?

I've read [this page here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-vs-restcontroller), but it only says that I don't need the @ResponseBody annotation, which my instructor isn't using anyways.  Is this because of the different IDEs?  or maybe something to do with the Deployment automation software?  or something else entirely?  What can I do to get the @Controller annotation to work as the instructor is using it?

EDIT:

I just noticed that my code, when running with @RestController, only shows the words "main-menu" on the page.  I'm trying to load a page called "main-menu.jsp".

Here's my folder structure

[image]

The file spring-mvc-demo-servlet contains the below code for the bean:

```
<bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

Edit 2:

For starting the program, I am using a main method that is auto-generated by IntelliJ.

SpringMvcDemoApplication.java

```
package com.example.springdemo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication()
public class SpringMvcDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringMvcDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <display-name>spring-mvc-demo</display-name>

    <absolute-ordering />

    <!-- Spring MVC Configs -->

    <!-- Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!-- Step 3: Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.springdemo" />

    <!-- Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="\WEB-INF\view" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

My application.properties

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

Edit 3:

Here's my error stack strace:

```
2021-06-27 17:21:17.573 DEBUG 7824 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/", parameters={}
2021-06-27 17:21:17.573 DEBUG 7824 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.example.springdemo.HomeController#showPage()
2021-06-27 17:21:17.574 DEBUG 7824 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
2021-06-27 17:21:17.575 DEBUG 7824 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : View name 'main-menu', model {}
2021-06-27 17:21:17.575 DEBUG 7824 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to [main-menu]
2021-06-27 17:21:17.575 DEBUG 7824 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "FORWARD" dispatch for GET "/main-menu", parameters={}
2021-06-27 17:21:17.576 DEBUG 7824 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [Classpath [META-INF/resources/], Classpath [resources/], Classpath [static/], Classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2021-06-27 17:21:17.582 DEBUG 7824 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2021-06-27 17:21:17.582 DEBUG 7824 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "FORWARD" dispatch, status 404
2021-06-27 17:21:17.583 DEBUG 7824 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2021-06-27 17:21:17.583 DEBUG 7824 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2021-06-27 17:21:17.583 DEBUG 7824 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2021-06-27 17:21:17.585 DEBUG 7824 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
2021-06-27 17:21:17.586 DEBUG 7824 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
```

Edit 4:

I've rebuilt the project using Thymeleaf, as suggested by @chrylis.  I am still getting errors, but the stack is ddifferent.  Here is the new stack.

```
2021-06-27 20:51:15.304 ERROR 42244 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template "main-menu": Error resolving template [main-menu], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [main-menu], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:869) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:607) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) [thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) [thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:366) [thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) [thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1396) [spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1141) [spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1080) [spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) [spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_291]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_291]

2021-06-27 20:51:15.307 ERROR 42244 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [main-menu], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers] with root cause

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [main-menu], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:869) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:607) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:366) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1396) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1141) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1080) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_291]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_291]
```

Edit 5:

Back to my original build, but getting rid of the web.xml, as user @Asmin suggested.  I seem to get a better stack trace, which now shows that it is attempting to open the file named main-menu.jsp.  However, it says Resource not found.  I'm tried changing the `spring.mvc.view.prefix` to read as

- `spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/`
- `spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/`
- `spring.mvc.view.prefix=/resource/WEB-INF/view/`
- `spring.mvc.view.prefix=F:/Projects/spring-mvc-demo/src/main/resources/WEB-INF/view/`

Every one of them returns the same stack trace of Resource not found.

```
2021-06-28 20:25:08.403 DEBUG 28116 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/", parameters={}
2021-06-28 20:25:08.406 DEBUG 28116 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.example.springdemo.mvc.HomeController#showPage()
2021-06-28 20:25:08.420 DEBUG 28116 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
2021-06-28 20:25:08.420 DEBUG 28116 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : View name 'main-menu', model {}
2021-06-28 20:25:08.421 DEBUG 28116 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to [/WEB-INF/view/main-menu.jsp]
2021-06-28 20:25:08.424 DEBUG 28116 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "FORWARD" dispatch for GET "/WEB-INF/view/main-menu.jsp", parameters={}
2021-06-28 20:25:08.426 DEBUG 28116 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [Classpath [META-INF/resources/], Classpath [resources/], Classpath [static/], Classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2021-06-28 20:25:08.426  WARN 28116 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Path with "WEB-INF" or "META-INF": [WEB-INF/view/main-menu.jsp]
2021-06-28 20:25:08.426 DEBUG 28116 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2021-06-28 20:25:08.426 DEBUG 28116 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "FORWARD" dispatch, status 404
2021-06-28 20:25:08.427 DEBUG 28116 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2021-06-28 20:25:08.428 DEBUG 28116 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2021-06-28 20:25:08.428 DEBUG 28116 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2021-06-28 20:25:08.442 DEBUG 28116 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
2021-06-28 20:25:08.445 DEBUG 28116 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect the behavior to be? Have you [_read the documentation_](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html) for `@RestController`?

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking here. I'm expecting a page to load which contains my main-menu.jsp file in the body of the page. I linked to a page where I read about the differences in the 2 annotations. Like I said in my post, the only difference between `@Controller` and `@RestController` is that the `@RestController` bundles `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody`. The instructor's code doesn't use `@ResponseBody`, but runs fine with `@Controller`. Why doesn't mine work the same way as his?

Comment: It appears from your error message that you're using Spring Boot, which is the modern way to build Spring applications, but that `bean` XML snippet suggests that you're trying to mix configuration strategies (specifically, configuring for use in an external container instead of using the modern "just run `main`" approach). You'll need to provide more information about how you're launching the application.

Comment: I've added my files to the original question.  I am definitely using a main method to start my application, which is auto-generated by IntelliJ.  I did notice that the instructor doesn't have a main method.  In Eclipse, he simple right-clicked on the package and selected run as >>> run on server.  It appears from your comment I have to adjust the xml file he gave me to allow me to run from main method?

Comment: Your instructor appears to be using an outdated setup (that "run on server" bit). Are you required to follow along precisely for a course?

Comment: No, this is a Udemy course.  I can change anything I want to make it work.  I'm only using IntelliJ with Gradle because that's what my company is using, and I want to learn as closely to what we use as possible.

Comment: In that case, I recommend (1) [using Thymeleaf instead of JSP](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) (it fixes a number of annoying problems, including testability) and (2) adopting the Spring Boot defaults, which in this case means putting your template at `src/main/resources/templates/main-menu.html` (no config required, just include the Thymeleaf starter).

Comment: That didn't work.  Now I'm getting a new error about Thymeleaf and the web.xml file doesn't recognize the dispatcher servlet name or mapping.

Comment: You should not have any `web.xml` at all in a jar Boot project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into similar problem few days back. It appears you are trying to use Spring Boot.Please, try removing web.xml and make certain changes as below code snippets. This is working for me.

DemoApplication.java

```
    @SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication  extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(DemoApplication.class);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix= /WEB-INF/

spring.mvc.view.suffix= .jsp
```

[Project Structure for adding jsp files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZXx1.png)

Home Controller.java

```
@Controller
@Slf4j
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        log.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

        return "home1";
    }
}
```

PS: This is configuration for running with @Controller.

Comment: Hi Asmin, your suggestion worked great to get my build, but now it seems that it isn't recognizing the folder that my view is located in.  Do you have any suggestions that my help to get it running?  I've updated my post with a 5th Edit that contains what I've done so far and my stack trace.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: On second thought, I believe I'm going to need to open a new question.  You're solution worked for my initial question of how to get `@Controller` to work in my code.  The new issue now shows that the resource cannot be found.  Thank you for your help.  I will go ahead and mark your answer as the solution.

Comment: @skidwiz please try the project structure as I have attached with my answer and bring your views outside of resources into new folder webapp. And let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is check the simple difference between `@Controller` and `@RestController`

when you are using simple `@Controller` it simply create a map model and return a view but in real time we need json responses in our Rest APIS ,so to do that you need to use `@RestController`, because

`@RestController` = `@Controller`+`@ResponseBody`
but when you are using `@Controller` you must have to use `@ResponseBody` if you want written data directly in JSON.

Thanks

Here is the reference

[https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2017/08/difference-restcontroller-controller-annotation-spring-mvc-rest.html#:~:text=The%20%40Controller%20is%20a%20common,of%20%40Controller%20%2B%20%40ResponseBody%20](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2017/08/difference-restcontroller-controller-annotation-spring-mvc-rest.html#:%7E:text=The%20%40Controller%20is%20a%20common,of%20%40Controller%20%2B%20%40ResponseBody%20).